# Subtracting Query Values

Tags: php, math

I am trying to make two queries providing $result and $result2.  I would like to subtract the two results to create a total for the vote (negative vote being possible).  Therefore on an empty query the result value would have to be zero.

My subtraction function isn't working.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  I am getting no result.

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_votes WHERE vote_com_writer_id = "'.$d['user_id'].'" AND vote_com_rank = "1"');
        $positive_votes = mysql_result($result, 0);


$result2 = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment_votes WHERE vote_com_writer_id = "'.$d['user_id'].'" AND vote_com_rank = "2"');
        $negative_votes = mysql_result($result2, 0);


list($vote) = $positive_votes - $negative_votes;
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of negative and positive vote variables?

Comment: Hi David, yes.  I am getting values for my $positive_votes and $negative_votes.  I am wondering if my subtraction function is wrong with using the list?  Can't quite figure it out.

Comment: I've never seen list() used like that, generally its an array passed to it. Have you tried without list() ? $vote = $pos - $neg;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the basics.

1. Confirm that your sql queries work by manually executing them against your database.
2. Confirm that $postive_votes and $negative_votes are what you expect with something like the following:

   > echo 'Positive Votes: '.$positive_votes.', Negative Votes: '.$negative_votes.
3. remove list($vote) as it is not being used correctly. The [list function](http://php.net/list) is intended for arrays not the results of subtraction. Replace that line with the following:

   > $total_votes = $positive_votes - $negative_votes;
   >
   > echo 'Total Votes:'.$total_votes;

.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Brett. The list was the problem.